# How can you set the MessageId of a Service Bus message using the Azure Functions output binding?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

How can you set the MessageId of a Service Bus message using the Azure Functions output binding?

I've got the function writing to the SB topic fine with the following output binding in my pre-compiled C# Function App ...

```
[ServiceBus("targettopic", Connection = "SbConnectionString")]
    out PersonEvent outPerson,
```

But I need to set the MessageId to use in the duplicate detection history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to return an instance of `BrokeredMessage` type instead of your custom class. That will enable you to set any property including message ID.

Comment: Rats ... I had a thought that'd be the way. Yeap, that works a treat, but now any subscriber has to handle the body as a BrokeredMessage  :-(

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need to encode the body exactly as subscriber expects

Comment: Any idea how to handle with javascript azure functions?